# Combining columns in a grid

Tags: powerbi, measure

The table visualization, below, is made up of columns from different tables.  I need the Enquiries and Variations columns to be added together and totaled below.  What is the best way to accomplish this?  These columns are all from different tables, hinging back onto the Region.  Any thoughts and help is greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: I accomplished this by using a measure. My first one! Yahhhhh!